# lightbox doesn't work in Google Maps info window generated by JSON

Tags: json, wordpress, google-maps-markers, lightbox

I have a page which contains Google Maps with multiple locations based on Google Maps JavaScript API. Markers and info windows are generated by JSON like this:

```
init_markers([{
  "id":1,
  "lat":"52.24125614966341",
  "lng":"19.9072265625",
  "address":"Adress",
  "infowindow":"<div class=\"photo\">
                <a rel=\"lightbox\" href=\"http://exapmle.com/lol.jpg\">
               <img src=\"http://exapmle.com/lol.jpg\" \/> <\/a><\/div>"},        
{next_marker...}]);
```

The problem is that the lightbox doesn't work in info window on the map. Instead the lightbox image opens in an empty browser tab. Outside the map the lightbox work fine.

I'm using WordPress, all links are generated by looping through posts and getting post thumbnails.

Has anybody had the same problem and found a solution?

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers?

Comment: Yes, it happens in all browsers